# Replace keyup event with some input detect event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getRandom(){return Math.ceil(Math.random()* 20);}

function createSum(){
 var randomNum1 = getRandom(),
   randomNum2 = getRandom();
 total =randomNum1 + randomNum2;
 $( "#question" ).text( randomNum1 + " + " + randomNum2 + "=" );
    

  $("#ans").val('');
  checkInput();
}

function checkInput(){
  var input = $("#ans").val(), 
     slideSpeed = 200,
      hasInput = !!input, 
      valid = hasInput && input == total;
   
    $('#message').toggle(!hasInput);
    $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !valid);  
    $('#success').toggle(valid);
    $('#fail').toggle(hasInput && !valid);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 //create initial sum
 createSum();
 // On "reset button" click, generate new random sum
 $('button[type=reset]').click(createSum);
 // On user input, check value
 $( "#ans" ).on('input', checkInput);
});

var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;

var output = document.getElementById('ans');
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  output.textContent = event.results[0][0].transcript;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="question"></p><input id="ans" type="text">
   <div id="message">Please verify.</div>
   <div id="success">Validation complete :)</div>
   <div id="fail">Validation failed :(</div>
      
<button onclick="recognition.start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="recognition.stop()">Stop</button>
```

I have a function which check weather the input is correct or not and upon checking the input it gives message like complete or failed.

```
<p id="question"></p><input id="ans" type="text">
<div id="message">Please verify.</div>
<div id="success">Validation complete :)</div>
<div id="fail">Validation failed :(</div>
```

I am checking input with the help of keyup event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
createSum();
$('button[type=reset]').click(createSum);
// On user input, check value
$( "#ans" ).keyup(checkInput);    // keyup event
});
```

And this code is working fine. But I decided to take input by voice using a speech-to-text API instead of a keyboard input. Now my checkInput function doesn't run because there is no keyup event. My query is is there a replacement for this event which can run my checkInput function if it finds a value in input box.

I tried onchange but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: May be you are looking for `.on('input', `

Comment: tried this `$( "#ans" ).on('input', checkInput);` doesn't work

Comment: `$( "#ans" ).on('input', function(){checkInput(); });`

Comment: nope. I still need to click on input box for results. Check the snippet

Answer (score 0):

//I think this may help you

```
recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  iput
}
```

Comment: browser compatibility is bad https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/onspeechend